# React-Native navigation - navigation.navigate doesn't pass route params

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-navigation-stack

I'm trying to pass a roomID between components in React-Native using the React-Native navigator (v6) method. I destructure {navigation, route} and route is always undefined, but it shouldn't be. I'm using `@react-navigation/native-stack : "^6.1.0"`. I'm new to React in general so there are defintely inefficiences with how I inject Redux / Stack Navigators:

package.json versions:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-peerjs": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^1.92.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Redux from './Redux';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Home from './Home';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AppRedux = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Room" component={Redux} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AppRedux);
```

redux.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import store from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';

const Redux = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
        <Provider {...{ store }}>
            <PaperProvider>
                <App navigation={navigation} />
            </PaperProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
};

export default Redux;
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header';
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
    const subtitle = 'Video app';
    //room state
    const [room, setRoom] = React.useState('');
    return (
        <View>
            <Header />
            <Text style={styles.text}>{subtitle}</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Enter room name" onChange={(val) => (
                setRoom(val.nativeEvent.text)
            )} />
            <Button
                title="Go to Room"
                onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate('Room', { roomID: room });
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
...
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Button } from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/Header';

import {
  RTCView,
  mediaDevices,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';
import { joinRoom } from './store/actions/videoActions';

const height = 800;
const width = 400;

const App = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const video = useSelector(state => state.video);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const roomID = 'shouldnthavetohardcode';
  // console.log("roomID=", route.params.roomID);
  useEffect(() => {
    let isFront = true;
...
```

In App.js, `route` is undefined. I could put the roomID in Redux state, but I'd rather get this parameter passing working.

Even when passing in a hard-coded key:value pair, it is still undefined.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it right after posting. My navigator is spawning a Component from my `Redux.js` file. So `Redux.js` has the route state:

```
const Redux = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    return (
        <Provider {...{ store }}>
            <PaperProvider>
                <App navigation={navigation} roomID={route.params.roomID} />
            </PaperProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

I passed the `roomID` in as a prop from this Component to the App component. Obviously not ideal, and I need to refactor this code so Redux is higher in my component tree.